# R add arrays by column name

Tags: r

This seems really basic but I can't figure it out.  How do you add two arrays together in R by column name?  For example:

```
a<-matrix(1:9,ncol=3)
colnames(a)<-c("A","B","C")
a
#     A B C
#[1,] 1 4 7
#[2,] 2 5 8
#[3,] 3 6 9

b <-matrix(10:18,ncol=3)
colnames(b)<-c("C","B","D")
b
#      C  B  D
#[1,] 10 13 16
#[2,] 11 14 17
#[3,] 12 15 18
```

I would like to add them together in such a way to yield:

```
#      A  B  C  D
#[1,]  1 17 17 16
#[2,]  2 19 19 17
#[3,]  3 21 21 18
```

I suppose I could add extra columns to both matrices but it seems like there would be a one line command to accomplish this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `xtabs` , after melting a combined table to a long `data.frame`:

```
xtabs(Freq ~ ., data=as.data.frame.table(cbind(a,b)))
#    Var2
#Var1  A  B  C  D
#   A  1 17 17 16
#   B  2 19 19 17
#   C  3 21 21 18
```

The `rownames` will just be cycling through `LETTERS`

Answer (score 2):

We could use `melt/acast` from `reshape2` after `cbind`ing both the 'a' and 'b' matrices (inspired from @thelatemail's post).

```
library(reshape2)
acast(melt(cbind(a,b)), Var1~Var2, value.var='value', sum)
#  A  B  C  D
#1 1 17 17 16
#2 2 19 19 17
#3 3 21 21 18
```

---

Or we find the column names that are common in both by using `intersect`, column names that is found in one matrix and not in other with `setdiff`.  By subsetting both the matrices with the common names, we add it together, then `cbind` the columns in both 'a' and 'b' based on the `setdiff` output.

```
nm1 <- intersect(colnames(a), colnames(b))
nm2 <- setdiff(colnames(a), colnames(b))
nm3 <- setdiff(colnames(b), colnames(a))

cbind(a[,nm2, drop=FALSE], a[,nm1]+b[,nm1], b[,nm3,drop=FALSE])
#     A  B  C  D
#[1,] 1 17 17 16
#[2,] 2 19 19 17
#[3,] 3 21 21 18
```

---

Another option would be create another `matrix` with all the unique columns in 'a' and 'b', and then replace the values in that

```
nm <- union(colnames(a), colnames(b))
m1 <- matrix(0, ncol=length(nm), nrow=nrow(a), dimnames=list(NULL, nm))
m1[,colnames(a)] <- a
m1[,colnames(b)] <- m1[,colnames(b)] +b
m1
#     A  B  C  D
#[1,] 1 17 17 16
#[2,] 2 19 19 17
#[3,] 3 21 21 18
```

---

We could also `cbind` both the matrices and use `tapply` to get the `sum` after grouping with column and row indices

```
m2 <- cbind(a, b)
t(tapply(m2,list(colnames(m2)[col(m2)], row(m2)), FUN=sum))
```

Or we loop through 'nm' and get the `sum`

```
sapply(nm, function(i) rowSums(m2[,colnames(m2) ==i, drop=FALSE]))
```